# IE will not activate

Tags: autohotkey

***I want to Activate IE 11 if it is not active***

This is part of legacy tests, so it absolutely must be IE, not Edge or any other browser. I want to bring the IE window to the foreground so I can run F5 on it. Here is the code I'm using:

```
IfWinExist, ahk_exe iexplore.exe
{
  If WinActive ahk_exe iexplore.exe
  {
    msgbox, ie already active
  }
  Else
  {
    WinActivate, ahk_exe iexplore.exe
    msgbox, ie should now be active
  }
}
```

I have IE running, but minimized or under other windows. Running the above script produces a msgbox of `ie should now be active`, yet IE is definitely not active.

The crazy part is, if I physically press Ctrl+T (new Tab) after running the script, then ie comes to the forefront and a new tab is opened! But if I add `Send, ^T` to the script, nothing happens.

---

## *Things I've tried*

Here's a list of posts I found on Google, yet they didn't not work:

- https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/115943-ie-com-create-or-active/
- https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=30789
- https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm

Other things I tried:

- WinMaximize - causes my pc to freeze for about 3 minutes
- WinActivate, iFrame - same as ahk_exe
- WinActivate, ahk_class iFrame - same as ahk_exe
- WinActivate, "ahk_class iFrame" - same as ahk_exe
- DetectHiddenWindows/WinShow- same as ahk_exe
- ComObjActive("InternetExplorer.Application") - Operation unavailable error

It seems like IE will not come to the foreground in the same manner as other applications. I assume this is because of some way IE registers to windows, but is there a work-around?

Comment: I bet this has to do with all of the whacko integration with their other apps.  It might be running as a sub-process of some other thing.  Have you looked at your process tree with SystemInternals process explorer to see where it might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer starts up multiple processes, all of them are `iexplore.exe`,
just with different parameters. Your code just picks up the wrong one.

This will work better, using the window title to bring it forward:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinExist, Internet Explorer
{
  If WinActive ahk_exe iexplore.exe
  {
    msgbox, ie already active
  }
  Else
  {
    WinActivate, Internet Explorer
    msgbox, ie should now be active
  }
}
```

Comment: Jeeeeez. So much time for something so simple. Thanks man.